# Google Chrome new tab no longer showing Apps or working thumbnails

Tags: google-chrome, google-workspace

For the last few days, when I open a new tab in Chrome (on Windows 7), it no longer shows any arrow or other link to get to my web apps. It is also white, instead of using my theme as previously, with a huge GOOGLE search box - but the search box does not accept any text :( It still shows thumbnails of 8 frequent links, but the links do not work; if I click on one, it goes grey (and shows a closing cross), but does not take me to the web site.

The same behaviour is on several computers.
Any ideas? Can I get the old, functioning version back?

Comment: I would backup your history and bookmarks first. Than try re-installing Google chrome by downloading the installer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I don't like the behavior of the new tab page in Google Chrome 29.0.1547.76 (Official Build 223446) m. How can I restore the old behavior?](http://superuser.com/questions/650099/i-dont-like-the-behavior-of-the-new-tab-page-in-google-chrome-29-0-1547-76-off)

Comment: @ColinPickard technically that other article would be a duplicate of this one, as this one is older.  They should be merged...

Answer (score 1):

Disable "Instant Extended API" feature via `chrome://flags/#enable-instant-extended-api` to bring back the old behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to some malware or because of some chrome extension. Try disabling the extensions. If it does not solves the problem try re-installing.