# Old "New Tab" Page in a fresh install of Google Chrome 32

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

I just got a brand new PC with Windows 7 and installed Chrome (version 32).

I got an old "New Tab" page (with the App list and the recently visited websites), instead of the new layout with the Google logo (or the daily doodle), the search box, and the smaller recently visited websites.

It is also missing the "App" button in the favorites bar, and the App launcher in the taskbar.

I have older installs in other machines running with the same version of Chrome, but with the new behavior.

How can I get the new "New Tab" page?

[This is somehow the "reverse" of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/650099)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution myself, and it is actually the "reverse" of [the solution](https://superuser.com/a/650119/40690) of the "[opposite issue](https://superuser.com/q/650099/40690)".

I forced "Enabled" for "Enable Instant Extended API" (the default was "Automatic"... which probably on my systems defaults to "Disabled" for some reason).

Here's the flag:

```
chrome://flags/#enable-instant-extended-api
```

Now the question is: Google reverted the "New Tab" page default behavior, or it is something weird in my setup?

Comment: This no longer works. The flag is gone from chrome://flags