# Confirm enable-instant-extended-api flag exists as of latest Chrome stable?

Tags: google-chrome

As the title states, does `chrome://flags/#enable-instant-extended-api` still exist as of whatever the latest stable build is.

I know this question is rather easy to answer. All I'm looking for is simple verification as a comment towards the bottom of an [answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/650119/236545) claims it has been removed in the latest stable build:

> With the latest stable build - this solution (and those linked) no longer work. I did manage to find a work-around though.. Check out my answer below. No extensions required.

I'm not concerned currently with dev builds and can confirm that, for me, the flag does not appear in Chrome Version *34.0.1810.0 canary*.

Oddly enough, the flag still appears in Chrome Version *32.0.1700.102 m* which, as far as I can tell, is the latest stable build. I also cannot find any confirmation that the flag has been removed outside of the dev channels.

So again, can anyone confirm that this flag does/does not exist in the latest stable build of Google Chrome?

My full `chrome://version` is:

```
Google Chrome       32.0.1700.102 (Official Build 246481) m
OS                  Windows 
Blink               537.36 (@165586)
JavaScript          V8 3.22.24.17
Flash               12.0.0.41
User Agent          Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36
Command Line        "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin --disable-instant-extended-api --flag-switches-end
Executable Path     C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Profile Path        C:\Documents and Settings\Username\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Variations      6dcb530d-954431d1
                fde57b90-3d47f4f4
                514bad25-7215e5f8
                e950616e-ca7d8d80
                b178bdde-887f97ea
                8afebf76-21393788
                fd9e2196-9b833a7
                9e5c75f1-766fa2d
                24dca50e-837c4893
                ca65a9fe-91ac3782
                8d790604-9a6af412
                ea1014b7-dd21eb5a
                5a3c10b5-e1cc0f14
                244ca1ac-4ad60575
                f47ae82a-86f22ee5
                5e29d81-cf4f6ead
                3ac60855-486e2a9c
                246fb659-4ad60575
                f296190c-e7e0c21f
                4442aae2-6e3b1976
                ed1d377-e1cc0f14
                75f0f0a0-4ad60575
                e2b18481-cdc3d902
                e7e71889-4ad60575
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still exists it in 32.0.1700.102:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I see the same flag and it does appear to be working. Perhaps the user was mistaken, but he does mention build *32.0.1700.76* in his own answer. Odd.

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore: Not every Chrome install is created equal. You can check `chrome://version/` and see which *variations* were applied to your specific installation. I'm not trying to say that this is the cause for the observations here, but it might be :)

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome v33 you can use this extension http://stylet.github.io/GLogo_deactivator/ . I hope it's will be helpful.